# Symfony Form Builder HTTP Method doesn't register

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I am trying to create a form in Symfony using the form builder( without an Entity, if that's relevant). I can see the "_method" field with a value of "PATCH" in my html, but when I submit I get an error telling me that my route does not accept POST method.

I have tried putting $builder->setMethod('PATCH') in my form class:

```
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
      $builder->setMethod('PATCH');
      $builder
          ->add('image', FileType::class, [
              'constraints' => [
                  new NotBlank(),
              ]
          ])
          ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save Changes']);
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults([
          // Configure your form options here
      ]);
  }
}
```

and I have also tried putting method => PATCH in my createForm method:

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{

    public function update(Request $request): Response
    {

        $updateForm = $this->createForm(UpdateHeroType::class, null, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('webmaster_home_update'),
            'method' => 'PATCH',
        ]);

        return $this->renderForm(
            'Admin/home/index.html.twig',
            [
                'update_form' => $updateForm,
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know why I get an error saying that my route doesn't allow POST method when I can see that I have my method set to PATCH. This is my first time using Symfony for a project, so I might be overlooking something very basic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you enabled [Framework Configuration Reference (FrameworkBundle)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http_method_override)? See the bottom of the section of https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method

Comment: That worked! I imported the Request class and added "Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();" to index.php and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method), I needed to include the [Framework Configuration Reference (FrameworkBundle)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http_method_override).

Specifically, I need to add the following to `public/index.php`:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
```

This is because when using the method `PATCH`, Symfony still uses `POST` in the backend.

Comment: This could be done too by setting the framework option `http_method_override` to `true`